# Find and count "0" values in each series(column) in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

I have huge dataframe

[You can download my csv file](http://www.fiscalforecasting.com/data.csv)

91 columns (first=year, second=month, others:items) and 153 rows

[You can see in Rstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwYOk.png)

I have tried to find how much "0" values in each of series in my dataframe

But I can't write any function for this

How can I find these amounts for each series ?

What is wrong?

```
   count <- 0
```

for (i in data) 
{

length(data$i[data$i ==0.00])

count = count+1

}

print(count)

Sincerely

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and [mcve] Please use `dput(...)` to show your data or a definition of your dataframe. ... **i.e. edit your question!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to count how many 0 values you have in each column?

If so, you can use [apply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) function for each of the columns:

```
data <- data.frame( a = c(1,2,0,3), b = c(0,0,0,2) )
apply( data , 2 , function(x) sum ( x == 0 ) )
a b 
1 3
```

Comment: apply( main , 2 , function(x) sum ( x == 0 ) ) did not count or did not write any results

Comment: added reproducible example, hope this helps

Comment: Hi Adam, data <- data.frame( a = c(1:153), b = c(1:91) )                         
         Error in data.frame(a = c(1:153), b = c(1:91)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 153, 91

Comment: Data frame needs to have the same number of rows in each column, so: data.frame( a = c(1:91), b = c(1:91) ) or data.frame( a = c(1:153), b = c(1:153) )

Comment: Dear Adam, I have 153 rows and 91 columns ( I calculate for 89 columns) also I tried your new codes , didn't work

Comment: DearAdam, your codes are working, problem results from first NA values in my dataframe. When I changed the first NA values to numeric values, codes worked. Sincerely. Engin YILMAZ